# Ampersands in MUI styled CSS selectors

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

When exactly is the ampersand (`&`) needed before a CSS selector in MUI's `styled` function? For example, both the following two versions seem to work the same way:

```js
// With ampersand
const CssTextField = styled(TextField)({
  '& label.Mui-focused': {
    color: 'green',
  },
  '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
    borderBottomColor: 'green',
  },
  '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
    '& fieldset': {
      borderColor: 'red',
    },
    '&:hover fieldset': {
      borderColor: 'yellow',
    },
    '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
      borderColor: 'green',
    },
  },
});

// Without ampersand sometimes
const CssTextField = styled(TextField)({
  "label.Mui-focused": {
    color: "green"
  },
  ".MuiInput-underline:after": {
    borderBottomColor: "green"
  },
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    fieldset: {
      borderColor: "red"
    },
    ":hover fieldset": {
      borderColor: "yellow"
    },
    "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
      borderColor: "green"
    }
  }
});
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-oskar-xwe7ke?file=/demo.tsx:0-1280

I found that sometimes (but not always) removing an ampersand doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: I have been searching fot the answer for a while.